# Omettre "de" dans une plage de nombres

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Bonjour à tous.
J'ai une question intéressante d'un de mes étudiants débutant. Nous étudions les prépositions de et à pour indiquer une plage de temps ou d'espace: "du lundi au vendredi" ou "de 1 à 7". Mais en donnant les devoirs, je leur demande: "les exercices 1 à 7 p.32". La question: pourquoi omettre "de" devant exercice 1 dans ce cas. Est-ce correct? Quand et comment est-il possible d'omettre ce "de" de manière formelle ou informelle. Merci par avance pour vos éclaircissements

Comment: Je n'ai pas encore d'idée précise pour rédiger une réponse mais d'emblée pour moi on est devant des cas différents. *du lundi au vendredi* (ou *de mai à juin*, etc.) on définit une borne de début et une borne de fin avec un **singulier** à chaque fois. Par contre quand je dis *faites les exercices 1 à 7*, j'emploie un **pluriel** qui englobe tous les exos. « Pour le prochain cours lisez les pages 1 à 20 » mais « pour le prochain cours lisez de la page 1 à la page 20 ».

Comment: On peut dire les deux: _les exercices 1 à 7_ ou bien _les exercices de 1 à 7_. Dans les deux cas, le sens est le même, pas de confusion possible.

Answer (score 2):

Bonsoir,
votre question est pertinente. Plusieurs raisons peuvent expliquer l'utilisation correcte de l'expression *les exercices 1 à 32*.

On pourrait énoncer tout d'abord la **concision** du propos. En effet, l'omission de la préposition *de* rend la phrase plus concise sans sacrifier la clarté de celle-ci. De plus, le **contexte** implique qu'il s'agit d'une plage d'exercices, ce qui permet au lecteur de comprendre naturellement la phrase sans l'usage redondant de la préposition. Finalement, cette forme est utilisée à maintes reprises dans le **language courant** et permet d'apporter de la **fluidité** dans les propos, sans rendre la phrase trop lourde. Elle sera donc comprise par tout un chacun.

J'espère que cela vous aidera!